# compare two files column values

Tags: awk, sed

File1:

```
judi /var 80  
judi / 76  
judi /opt 85
```

File2:

```
judi /var 80  
judi / 80  
judi /opt 86
```

In the File2 "/" value is (80) high than File1 (76)
In the File2 "/opt" value is (86) high than File1 (85)

I need to get the output of only highest values

```
judi / 80  
judi /opt 86
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '$6>$3{print $4,$5,$6} $6<$3{print $1,$2,$3}'
judi / 80
judi /opt 86
```

#### How it works

- `paste file1 file2`

  This merges the lines together like:

  ```
  $ paste file1 file2
  judi /var 80    judi /var 80
  judi / 76       judi / 80
  judi /opt 85    judi /opt 86
  ```
- `$6>$3{print $4,$5,$6}`

  If the sixth field is larger than the third (meaning the value in file2 is larger than the value in file1), then print the values from file2.
- `$6<$3{print $1,$2,$3}`

  Alternatively, if the third field is larger than the sixth (meaning the value in file1 is larger than the value in file2), then print the values from file1.

#### Handling an alternate format

Suppose that each file can contain any number of space-separated fields while the number that we want to compare will always be the last field.  In that case:

```
$ awk -v f=file2 '{a=$0; n=$NF; getline <f} n>$NF{print a} n<$NF' file1
judi / 80
judi /opt 86
```

This reads from file1 and saves the whole line as variable `a` and the number in the last field as variable `n`.  It then, using `getline <f`, reads from file2 which puts file2's whole line in variable `$0` and last number in variable `$NF`.  We then make the comparisons and print out the desired line.

Comment: Nice use of paste +1, but wouldn't this break if `$2` or `$5` contains spaces.

Comment: @dev-null OK.  I added an approach for that.

Comment: nawk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}$3>a[$1$2]&&a[$1$2]{print $0}' File1 File2 , this one liner helped me , thanks @John1024